# 301 Redirect Loop www to non-www - Nginx + Apache2

Tags: redirect, ssl, apache, nginx

thanks for any help. I am not a server guy but I am dealing with a server at the moment. I have a site that is in a redirect loop from www to non-www. I am using a DigitalOcean Droplet with Ubuntu and Nginx for SSL. I originally had issues getting the SSL working and have created a config based on this post on StackExchange: [Wordpress redirect loop on nginx + apache reverse proxy](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/331234/wordpress-redirect-loop-on-nginx-apache-reverse-proxy). The main difference I had done was used a 302 redirect in the last server block. However someone told me to change it to 301 and now I am getting the loop from www to non-www. Below is my config file.

```
server {
        server_name .mysite.com;
        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php index.html;

        gzip on;
        gzip_types application/javascript image/* text/css;
        gunzip on;

        location ~\.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg) {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location / {
                try_files $uri @apache;
        }

        location ~[^?]*/$ { # proxy directories
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ { # serve php files
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        }

        location @apache { # used by location /
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
        }


        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

        listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
        listen 443 ssl;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/privkey.pem;
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Note: changing the 301 back to 302 did not fix the problem.

Please help, thank you!

Edit: I have also confirmed there are no references to www.mysite.com in the database. I have used WP-CLI to find any. And the Home and Site URLs have always been without www.

Comment: Have you tried using "Better Search Replace". I often had the domain in the GUIDs which were also used for redirects, etc., but are not replaced by most search/replace tools. Just remove the checkmark for GUIDs and try to replace the www for the non-www variant.

Comment: @Tobias I have no access to the wp-admin as of now becuase of the loop.

Comment: You can also do a search and replace via PHPMyAdmin.